# Copying string with al_ustr_newf Allegro 5

Tags: c++, string, stdstring, allegro5

I tried to make a leaderboard in my game but I've encountered a problem which I can't figure out. 
I have strings with names and integers with score from my text file. I try to copy them to `ALLEGRO_USTR` to show it on screen.

When I use `al_ustr_newf("%s", name1)`, it copies some random signs.

```
fstream file2;
file2.open("leaderboard.txt", ios_base::in);

string name1;
string name2;
string name3;
int temp_score1;
int temp_score2;
int temp_score3;

file2 >> name1 >> temp_score1;
file2 >> name2 >> temp_score2;
file2 >> name3 >> temp_score3;

ALLEGRO_USTR * ustr_name1 = NULL;
ustr_name1 = al_ustr_newf("%s", name1);
```

Maybe there's another way to copy strings in allegro 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`al_ustr_newf` reference](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_ustr_newf):

> Create a new string using a printf-style format string.
>
> Notes:
>
> The "%s" specifier takes C string arguments, not ALLEGRO_USTRs. Therefore to pass an ALLEGRO_USTR as a parameter you must use al_cstr, and it must be NUL terminated. If the string contains an embedded NUL byte everything from that byte onwards will be ignored.

That being said, `al_ustr_newf("%s", name1);` is undefined behaviour, iterating through your stack variables until it finds a `NUL` byte. Address of `std::string` is almost never the same as an address of the actual buffer.

Use `al_ustr_newf("%s", name1.c_str());`, just like you'd have to do with `printf` and `std::string`.